# Saving objects to the app, IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

My app in development is related to survey questions. (fun ones, not boring ones!) I want to create a tier system for each question relative to the user, each time they answer a specific question I want to associate a value to that question for that user, identifying how many times they've answered it.

I believe the way I need to achieve this is `NSMutableDictionary` and `NSUserDefaults`. This is a simplified version of my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *questionTierDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"questionTiers"];

[questionTierDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4] forKey:@(2)];


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSLog(@"%@", questionTierDictionary);
```

Does this code save this data indefinitely to the app, or does it disappear once the user has closed the app? If so, do you have any suggestions on how I can easily test to see if the data was stored?

Comment: NSUserDefaults stores the value until your app is removed from the phone or you remove it manually by coding .

Comment: Edited the aspects of your question that would flag it for deletion. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further information.

Comment: sorry about that, thank you!

Comment: You might also want to look at Realm for data persistence https://realm.io/

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking into it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` save data permanently in you application directory till you remove it manually... to save a object in `NSUserDefaults` code like this

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"yourObject",@"yourKey", nil];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:dict forKey:@"dict"];

//fetch Like this

NSDictionary *dict1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dict"];
```

Comment: ok I think I see what was confusing me. When I do this:

NSLog(@"%@", questionTierDictionary);

its not going to log all the keys that were created beyond what was just added in that array on the specific load, right? 

I was thinking it would log all the keys that have been added on any prior load as well.

Comment: now, when I try to fetch the data I get               

    **2015-12-29 21:06:42.223 NSDictionary Tutorial[45038:3250755] (null)**
                   
Shouldn't it be logging a 4 instead?

Comment: check my updated answere.. you are not saving object in dictionary correctly

Answer (score 1):

sandbox  path ：

~~ Documents:

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

~~~ Caches:

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachesDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

~~~ tmp:

NSString *tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();

~~~ home sandbox:

NSString *homeDir = NSHomeDirectory();

~~~ for pic :

NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"apple" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *appleImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

---

Example:

---

```
NSFileManager* fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![fm fileExistsAtPath:[self dataFilePath]]){
    //
    [fm createDirectoryAtPath:[self dataFilePath] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

    //
    NSArray *files = [fm subpathsAtPath: [self dataFilePath] ];

    //
    NSData *data = [fm contentsAtPath:[self dataFilePath]];

    //
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentOfPath:[self dataFilePath]];
}
```

---

I hope I could help you!

---